# Will BoxStarter's Install-WindowsUpdate reboot the machine?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update, chocolatey

I use BoxStarter Install-WindowsUpdate to keep my development machines up to date. I run it from the PowerShell commandline.

`PS C:\Users\Administrator> Install-WindowsUpdate`

I think I one time noticed that the machine rebooted. However, especially on a couple months old base VM it happens that `Install-WindowsUpdate` will install dozens of updates, then reports it is done, while there are more updates after rebooting the VM manually. I would like BoxStarter to install updates, reboot, and repeat until there are no more updates. Is that possible?

I know that BoxStarter's promise is that it reboots the machine if required, but mayve you need to run a BoxStarer script for that from the WebLauncher (http://boxstarter.org/package/nr/url?[script-location]). In my use case I am running the BoxStarter [WinConfig feature](http://boxstarter.org/WinConfig) from PowerShell.

Comment: Note that the /nr/ that you have in your URL will explicitly prevent reboots, so at the very least you need to remove that if you are calling a script that will require a reboot (Windows Updates, .NET Framework install, etc).

Answer (score 3):

`Install-WindowsUpdate` will reboot your machine but it must be run from inside a boxstarter package. It will not work as intended if run directly from the commandline. I created a chocolatey package `Boxstarter.WindowsUpdate` that contains just Install-WindowsUpdate. So you could install that via boxstarter using: `Install-BoxstarterPackage`.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I will try to run Install-BoxstarterPackage from PowerShell. I found your windows update package on Chocolaty.

Comment: @matt-wrock Does Invoke-Boxstarter accept an inline script block like `Invoke-Boxstarter { Install-WindowsUpdate -all } or do you have to write it to a file first so, `(Set-Content script.ps1 "Install-WindowsUpdate -all") | Invoke-Boxstarter script.ps1`? The latter might be a workaround if it doesn't support arbitrary script block/objects.